# How to send get request when my input will be not null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to send get request with `startDate` and `finishDate` to get method(/api/documents/vacation/holydays) and return back new number(number vacation days without holidays).

[Here is my input picture](https://photos.app.goo.gl/AhTRnvgsLR2nKwkt5)

```
<DatePicker label="Дата начала"
    minDate={moment().toDate()}
    maxDate={endDate}
    value={startDate}
    dateFormat="DD.MM.YYYY"
    onDateChange={this.onChangeStartDate}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before sending the input check the value having null or not

```
{variable === null && typeof variable === "object")}
```

In a real scenario, the code will be

```html
<DatePicker label="Дата начала"
    minDate={moment().toDate()}
    maxDate={endDate === null && typeof endDate === "object ? '' : endDate}
    value={startDate === null && typeof startDate === "object ? '' : startDate}
    dateFormat="DD.MM.YYYY"
    onDateChange={this.onChangeStartDate}/>
```

If the endDate will be null it will not send anything until endDate doesn't get any value

**In another scenario if you want the component only work when it is, not null**

```html
{endDate === null && typeof endDate === "object ? <DatePicker/> :
<DatePicker label="Дата начала"
    minDate={moment().toDate()}
    maxDate={endDate}
    value={startDate}
    dateFormat="DD.MM.YYYY"
    onDateChange={this.onChangeStartDate}/>}
```